# How can I see a music sheet on Mozilla Firefox under Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, music, browser

I would like to see a music sheet on the Internet. I saw it on Mozilla Firefox. The error message is the following:

Your browser has been detected as: Firefox for Unknown Platform

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Firefox sends a string to the website, identifying your computer OS and browser version. This is called the User Agent.

Try installing the Switch User Agent-add on. Then, choose a different User Agent (e.g. Firefox for Windows), and things should be OK.

Comment: @Jos: 3 upvotes on a comment...  You should convert that to an answer...

Comment: @Fabby I may be too reticent in answering as long as I feel that the original question has not been fully answered. However, in this case, you are right, this comment would probably be useful to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox sends a string to the website, identifying your computer OS and browser version. This is called the User Agent. Try installing the Switch User Agent-add on for Firefox. Then, choose a different User Agent (e.g. Firefox for Windows), and things should be OK.